# Need help to generate SQL Server query to generate a grade on the basis of average marks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    [rollNo], AVG([marks])
FROM 
    [dbo].[ALL_REC]
GROUP BY 
    [rollNo]
```

Now what I need help with is is with calculation how to return the 3rd column for grades.

I need it to be:

1. 'A' for average marks greater than 90.
2. 'B' for average marks greater than 80.
3. 'C' for average marks greater than 70.
4. 'D' for average marks greater than 60.
5. 'F' for average marks less than 60.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    [rollNo], AVG([marks]) [Average],
    CASE 
       WHEN AVG([marks]) >= 90 THEN 'A'
       WHEN AVG([marks]) BETWEEN 80 AND 89 THEN 'B'
       WHEN AVG([marks]) BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN 'C'
       WHEN AVG([marks]) BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN 'D'
       ELSE 'E' 
    END [Grade]
FROM [dbo].[ALL_REC]
GROUP BY [rollNo];
```